# Пароль на Линукс?

Tags: настройки, linux

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, в какой директории находятся пароли для root и user. Не можем никак сменить пароль, чтобы обновить браузер и флешплеер в нетбуке. По умолчанию в буке стоит пользовательский пароль, а в букваре на нетбук нет пароля для root. Операционная система в нетбуке `Debian GNU/Linux 4.0\n\l`.

Пробовали установить Линукс-Слакс с флешки. Загрузился, как допсистема, но не смогли настроить интернет, а именно, соединение нетбука с модемом.

Заранее всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вам ответили в первом вашем вопросе Посмотрите ссылку и выполните 4 пункта, что следуют за Восстановление пароля в Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Edubuntu:

заканчивается набором passwd После этого введите и подтвердите новый пароль для рутаВсе! Перезагрузка Запускаем терминал -- su -- вводим пароль рута и работаем с его правами!

P.S. и с успехом кончаем систему!!!  :)  как я понял, она у вас до сих пор жива только от того, что вы эти два года не знали как зайти под рутом

Answer (score 0):

Пароли сохраняются в виде хэша, это раз. Во-вторых, может не быть прав на редактирование файла обычным пользователем. Сам файл по умолчанию хранится в /etc/passwd. Как вариант, можно попробовать загрузиться с LiveCD, примонтировать диск и попытаться отредактировать указанный файл, заменив хэш рута хешем пользователя. В указанном файле пароля root может и не быть, тогда он хранится в /etc/shadow, но там вроде как появляются дополнительные сложности.

Answer (score 0):

обычно на live CD (вроде даже и на слаксе) на рута можно сделать команду sudo su либо не потребует пароля, либо как у юзера. В крайнем случае, загрузись в single режиме (в венде аналог - safe mode) и смени пароль passwd root/ http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grub-boot-into-single-user-mode/